# Playing Youtube Video from UIWebView inside UIModalPresentationPageSheet limits full screen to size of modal view

Tags: objective-c, video, uiwebview, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have UIWebView inside a modal popover that's a PresentationPageSheet style. When Youtube videos are played in full screen the expected behaviour is for them to popover full screen. Instead they just play inside the popover controllers dimensions. [image]

Comment: Of course they only expand to fill their container!  It would be dangerous for any web frame to be able to expand full-screen and leap put of its bounds on iOS, it implies that the DOM knows too much about the windowing system.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that you have to embed the video inside an iframe.

```
if (self.youTubeID) {
    NSString *embeddedYouTubeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@",self.youTubeID];
    //NSString *controls = @"?controls=2&autohide=1";
    self.webView.opaque = NO;
    self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!DOCTYPE HTML><head></head><html><body><iframe width='%f' height='%f' src='%@' allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>", self.webView.frame.size.width *2, self.webView.frame.size.height*2, embeddedYouTubeURL];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil]; }
```